# Spotipy: Wrong/Several artist coming up when I use sp.search()

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am using the Spotify API (with the Spotipy Wrapper) on a small personal project. This is the call that I am using

`sp.search(q=band,limit=10)`

When I use a name like "Beck" I also get results from "Becky G". Is there a way to limit artists to a particular band or to search for an artist ID by name?

I tried the artist tag but that wasn't quite working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type` to limit your query. For example, try: `sp.search(q='Beck', type='artist', limit=10)`

Answer (score 0):

I've just submitted a very similar question before I found this, I don't have a direct answer I'm afraid but in my case I discovered I was getting false matches on in particular Artists in particular with names of 5 characters or less.

My workaround was to do a lookup on the artist, do a string match on the named returned from the Spotipy API using the fuzzywuzzy module. If that didn't give me an exact match, I pulled back ten and again used the fuzzywuzzy module to find the closest string match from all 10.